# Generator x Sequence no Firebird

Tags: firebird

Quando utilizar Generator e quanto utilizar Sequence no Firebird?

Qual diferença entre os dois?

Existe diferença de performance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

É exatamente a mesma coisa. `GENERATOR` era a sintaxe antiga que ainda é aceita, mas deve ser preferida `SEQUENCE` que é mais padrão SQL.

Este recurso é usado para criar identidade única e sequencial para linhas, geralmente usado em coluna como chave primária, onde o `ID` é o nome mais comum. Na maior parte dos casos funciona como uma chave substituta. O maior número possível é 2 elevado a 64.

[Documentação](http://www.firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd25-ddl-sequence.html).

[No 3.0 é possível usar um novo tipo que podemos chamar de `IDENTITY`](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/release_notes/html/en/3_0/rnfb30-ddl-enhance.html#rnfb30-ddl-identity) que faz todo o processo automaticamente.

Comment: Mas ainda preciso criar uma trigger?

Comment: Sim, precisa. Só no 3.0 existe outro tipo de coluna que automatiza todo o processo.